# Meteor not adding and showing tasks in web page, it just blinks and malfunctions (To create Todos list to add and delete tasks)

Tags: meteor

//Client side code  in client\main.js

Tasks=new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

```
Template.tasks.helpers({
    tasks:function () {
        return Tasks.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    }
});

Template.tasks.events({
    "submit .add-task":function (event) {
        var name = event.target.name.value;

        Meteor.call('addTask',name);
        event.target.name.value='';

        return false;
    },
    "click .delete-task":function (event) {
        if(confirm('Delete Task?')){
            Meteor.call('deleteTask',this._id);
        }
        return false;
    }
});

Meteor.methods({
    addTask: function (name) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('No Access!!');

        }
        Tasks.insert({
            name: name,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            userId: Meteor.userId()
        });
    },
    deleteTask: function(taskId) {
        Tasks.remove(taskId);
    }
});
```

---

//Server side code  in server\main.js

```
Tasks=new Mongo.Collection('tasks');



Meteor.methods({
    addTask: function (name) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('No Access!!');

        }
        Tasks.insert({
            name: name,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            userId: Meteor.userId()
        });
    },
    deleteTask: function taskId() {
        Tasks.remove(taskId);
    }
});
```

---

//Html page

```
<head>
  <title>tasklist</title>
</head>

<body>

  {{> tasks}}
</body>

<template name="tasks">
    {{> loginButtons}}
    <h1>Add Task</h1>
    {{#if currentUser}}
    <form class="add-task">
        <label>Task Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Add Task" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
        {{else}}
        <p>Please log in to add tasks</p>
        {{/if}}
<hr />
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
<ul>
    {{#each tasks}}
        <li>{{name}}{{#if currentUser}} <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a>{{/if}} </li>
        {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

Please help, in this when i reload page it first add and and shows in the web-page and if i delete the try todelete the added then screen doesnot show even added tasks which are in MongoDB.
And when i do console, there is an empty array of added tasks

Comment: This was working properly before adding Meteor insecure application.Malfunctions when i added insecure accounts command through command prompt.

Comment: Still we need more insight on the problem you are facing, open the console and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If it "blinks" this often means that your Method worked client side but not server side. The insert worked on your Minimongo (client) but not on the real MongoDB (server). So Meteor decide to rollback your insert on Minimongo.

You must have a problem inside your Method server side:
You can't use `Meteor.userId()` server side in your Methods, you have to use `this.userId`.
To avoid mistakes, only use this.userId inside the Meteor Methods client or server side.

```
// Server side
Meteor.methods({
    addTask: function (name) {
        if (!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('No Access!!');

        }
        Tasks.insert({
            name: name,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            userId: this.userId
        });
    },
    deleteTask: function taskId() {
        Tasks.remove(taskId);
    }
});
```

In Meteor, you don't have to duplicate your Methods client AND server side.

> Methods should always be defined in common code loaded on the client and the server to enable Optimistic UI.

You just have to define your Methods and your collection one time inside a folder loaded on client and server. For exemple you can put your code inside a folder named `both/`.

Comment: You can use Meteor.userId() in both server and client sides as of Meteor v1.5.1.

Comment: it stills blinks